# How would I solve a chaotic function for x?

Tags: trigonometry, chaos-theory

I need a chaotic function and a way to unsolve it for a project I have, but I don't know how I would go about undoing a chaotic function such as `y=10(sin(x)^5+cos(x)^10)` (I guess that isn't truly chaotic, just made it up in 5 mins but it's close enough for what I need to do).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A lot of functions do not have inverses (even locally). For example, functions as simple as $y(x)=xe^x$ or $y(x)=x\sin(x)$ do not have an inverse in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) ("easy" functions like $e^x$, $x^n$, $\cos(x)$, $\arctan(x)$, etc..). The function you have written down is unlikely to have an elementary inverse. In practice, what you do if you want to solve such an equation is use a numerical root finding method (e.g. bisection, Newton's method, secant method, etc..) to obtain an approximate solution for a given value of $y$.